# Call a method on every call

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, reflection

This can be a **debugging/monitoring** process.

I want to know a way, preferably the best way, of
**calling a method every time** other methods in a **class/namespace/application**
are executed.

Code snippets, opinions and articles would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AOP; look at PostSharp, for example, which offers this type of weaving. Note that this approach works by chaning the IL during the build process, and may impact runtime performance if over-used.

Comment: Thanks Mark, As I was searching I cam up with this platform, I was not familiar with this approach, Should I have make any changes in the structure of the project ?

Comment: @Sypress you would just have to add an assembly attribute (an "aspect").

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Aspect Oriented Programming(AOP).  A good library for this is [Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com).